# Type.GetProperties exclude properties with operator []

Tags: c#, .net

When I call

```
Type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
```

I also get properties with [] operators. So for instance I have:

```
MyType
-> Property1
-> Property2[string]
```

And the returned list of PropertyInfo contains both Property1 or Property2.

How do I exclude properties with operators?

I would prefer it to happen through bindingflags, but iterating through the PropertyInfo afterwords would be ok, but I can't see anything on the PropertyInfo class that indicates whether it has an operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's any `BindingFlags` value to exclude them right from the start, but you can use [`PropertyInfo.GetIndexParameters()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getindexparameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to filter properties: if a property is not indexed, it has no index parameters.

Answer (score 4):

You can use LINQ to solve this:

```
Type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(prop => prop.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0);
```

Comment: If you're going to use LINQ anyway, then `prop => !prop.GetIndexParameters().Any()` looks nicer to me.